# How to display custom field of component item of kit item on picking ticket - Netsuite

Tags: templates, netsuite, suitescript

I have invoiced a Kit Item that contains a few component items. I am able to print/display component item name and its description, but unable to display the `country of the manufacturer` and a `custom field` of the component item as shown below in the screenshot,

Note: this appears when print ic clicked on the invoice.

> every component has a different code and may have a different country
> manufacturing.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

@Mangrio unfortunately this is not standard functionality, which doesn't make sense.
You can use a suitelet to render the PDF template from the appropriate form, utilising a Saved Search to inject more data into the PDF, which tends to be slow, and is definitely extra time to build.
Other than that, I don't believe there is a solution.